# Service reference stops working when I make changes to WCF Service

Tags: .net, vb.net, wcf, visual-studio-2010

I'm using Visual Studio 2010 and .NET3.5. I've created a WCF service application.

I'm including two DLLs that contain the types I'm returning. The first method I wrote works both in WCF Test Client and also in a console application I created to test.

When I move on to the next method that returns a generic list of a type. It works great in WCF Test Client, but when I update the service reference it acts as if the service is unavailable.

All my objects say can't find reference, and I can no longer see it in the object browser. It's like it just disappears. I can still see it in the Service Reference folder.

If I go back to the WCF app and comment out the contract and implementation of that one method it work again. I created a local class very similar to the class I'm using from the dll, and the it works. Is there something I'm missing here? Can someone point me in the right direction?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Passing collections through WCF services can be tricky, especially if you're trying to use generic lists.

Generic lists aren't interoperable.  WCF services are intended to be usable by non-.net clients.  So, you have to jump through a couple of hurdles to make sure you can pass your collections through WSDL.

Check out this blog article ([link](http://www.request-response.com/blog/PermaLink,guid,ff5fab81-affb-4b2b-aa67-c80bdfc86cbd.aspx)).